# Finding the Yule-Nielsen factor

Tags: color, cmyk, color-theory, digital-printing

I have a rather technical question. I'm trying to find the Yule-Nielsen factor `n` in the equation

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neugebauer_equations

I've read that `n` is empirically derived from the "best fit" of the model to the training data:
[link here](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=OxlBqY67rl0C&pg=PA496&lpg=PA496&dq=yule%20nielsen%20factor%20best%20fit&source=bl&ots=Iy0lkrNVmf&sig=ACfU3U3oQFjXTllIguHSbgr1pTPSocs9Ew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia6OCCov3mAhXKwzgGHSXOAPcQ6AEwBXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=yule%20nielsen%20factor%20best%20fit&f=false)

My understanding is that the training data consists of random colour patches and the spectra of each is measured using a spectrophotometer. But how do you build the best-fit model of a collection of spectra? Suppose each spectrum is formulated as a `M` by one matrix. How do you come up with a best-fit model without knowing the value of `n`? Is the best-fit an `M` dimensional plane?

Comment: I think this is offtopic. Why would you expect designers to know this?

Comment: @Lucian I was hoping that some designer ran into a similar situation when calibrating or optimising their prints.

Comment: They would have to be _really_ passionate to go that far, but ok i guess.

Comment: Well yes really passionate and wasteful its easier to just measure and use icc profiles. Its not enoigh to measure once, machines and substrates age so you will keep continue doing this also you need to do it again once you have a batch of paper changed.

Comment: I'm curious about what you need this for. It's way beyond anything I ever needed to know doing design and prepress. For a designer preparing images for print this seems like extreme overkill, but maybe you are developing some kind of print method from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

The Yule-Nielsen equation is not relevant to colorspace, it’s a modifier in plate measurement related to the geometry/gain of the dot. Most use Murray-Davies... as mention earlier, this is way out of depth for graphic design, it’s a factor set inside measurement devices.

Answer (score 0):

I was first going to downvote, as this is obviously an engineering question. However, color reproduction science is so specialized and entangled with graphic arts, that I wouldn’t know where else to send you off to. So here we go:

The article is suggesting that you can find n by optimizing an error function, usually the sum of squares of all training data point errors. Better is to also find the parameters of the w functions through the same optimization.

But… note that the Neigebauer model has long been taken over by better multidimensional approximations: There are so many effects at play, that still today, the best press fingerprints are made just by sampling the entire input space, effectively turning the ‘model’ into a(glorified) interpolation formula.